# Angular 4 request fails due to missing CORS header after OPTIONS request succeeds

Tags: angular, cors

I'm experiencing the following issue: after the preflight OPTIONS requests succeeds, the subsequent POST request fails. This is kind of counter-intuitive as once the OPTIONS success, the subsequent request should be accepted.

The flow is as follows:

```
Request URL:https://<my aws hosted api endpoint>/pchacin/calc/sum
Request Method:OPTIONS

authority:<my aws end point>
method:OPTIONS
path:/pchacin/calc/sum
scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:ca,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,es-ES;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
access-control-request-headers:authorization,content-type
access-control-request-method:POST
origin:http://localhost:4200
referer:http://localhost:4200/calculator/sum
```

Response Headers

```
Status Code:200 
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent
access-control-allow-methods:OPTIONS,POST
access-control-allow-origin:*
content-length:0
content-type:application/json
```

Post request

```
Request URL:https://<my amazon end point>/pchacin/calc/sum
Request Method:POST

method:POST
path:/pchacin/calc/sum
scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/plain, */* 
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:ca,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,es-ES;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
authorization: <my security token>
content-length:13
content-type:application/json
origin:http://localhost:4200
referer:http://localhost:4200/calculator/sum
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 
Safari/537.36
```

Post response (notice is is returning 200 and I actually see the result content, so the backend is ok with the request)

```
content-length:12
content-type:application/json
date:Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:25:29 GMT .  
status:200
```

Error message

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: You need to configure the server to respond with a matching `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header otherwise the browser refuses to make the actual request. There is nothing Angular can do about it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I did this, in the OPTIONS method, but from the evidence, It's the actual POST request which is demanding the header. This is not what the [protocol says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), as I understand it.

Comment: The OPTIONS request always succeeds if the server doesn't return with an error response, but the browser won't even send the actual request if the header is not returned. Obviously returned header doesn't match the browsers expectations.

Comment: AFAIR if `credentials:true` is used `*` is not accepted for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Get he origin from the request and return this instead of `*` on the server, or add a static URL if it's known in advance.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I turned the credentials header to false (I had set to true at some point in my tests) but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: This is one of the most FAQ, there should be enough information available. Sorry, I monitor only `angular` and don't have the time to investigate.

Comment: Your understanding of the CORS protocol isn’t correct — the response to the POST request must also have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, because in order for browsers to allow your frontend code to access *any* response from any cross-origin request, the response must have Access-Control-Allow-Origin. And if you’re including credentials, the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot be the `*` wildcard; instead the value must be a single origin. So in that case you need to configure your server to return the actual origin value: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200/`

Answer (score 2):

I noticed with Angular 6 that a POST action is started by a OPTIONS request!

After implementing a OPTIONS handler in the backend, which returns a 200 status it was looking better.

In the OPTIONS request there is also a  "preflight request": Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type.

(Documentation quote: "The Access-Control-Request-Headers request header is used when issuing a preflight request to let the server know which HTTP headers will be used when the actual request is made.")

I fixed that by allowing the content-type (in the backend REST server): -"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, content-type'

And of course: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => '*'

Then, I got a GET and POST working!